# Concat variable with string in Azure ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I feel really dump right now but I just can't get this to work. Kind of new to ARM Templates so sorry for my ignorance.

I am trying to use a parameters.json with New-AzResourceGroupDeployment but I want to dynamically feed it in the VMName.

I am trying to use this for the NSG name:

> "value": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'-nsg')]"

But I get back an error of:

> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 6:39:21 AM - Error:
> Code=InvalidResourceName; Message=Resource name
> [concat(variables('vmName'),'-nsg')] is invalid. The name can be up to
> 80 characters long. It must begin with a word character, and it must
> end with a word character or with '*'. The name may contain word
> characters or '.', '-', '*'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where do you use the Concat function? Because ARM template functions are only available in the ARM template itself, not in the .parameters.json file.

Edit as a response:

It really depends on the use case but I would do something like this in the main ARM template if the 'nsg' value does not change for the given ARM template. If it does then define a second parameter 'vmsuffix' and concat both parameters into the full VMname.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {

    "VmName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": ""
    }

  },

  "variables": {
    "FullVmName": "[concat(parameters('VmName'), 'nsg')]"
  },

  "resources": [
    {
     ...
     ## Use the [variables('FullVmName') somewhere here
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I guess that could be it, I have used "[variables('diskName')]" in a parms file before, I just assumed I could use concat as well? If I cant what is the correct way to do this? I mean I can read the json into a var, change values, write a new temp file, then send that to New-AzResourceGroupDeployment I guess but that seems overkill.